# OpenCV 4.0: class "cv::FastFeatureDetector" has no member "DetectorType"

Tags: opencv

I tried to build OpenCV 4.0 using opencv_contrib and it didn't work.

`xfeatures2d.hpp` has the following line, and the error is in

> cv::FastFeatureDetector::DetectorType

```
CV_EXPORTS void FASTForPointSet( InputArray image, CV_IN_OUT std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints,
                  int threshold, bool nonmaxSuppression=true, cv::FastFeatureDetector::DetectorType type=FastFeatureDetector::TYPE_9_16);
```

I checked inside FasFeatureDetector and its parent, and the class really hasn't a definition for DetectorType.

I'm posting here to see if anyone else had this error, or if it's a bug with using OpenCV 4.0-alpha with opencv_contrib. If anyone can help, thank you.

Comment: I have found this enum [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp#L436)

Comment: For whatever reason, that enum wasn't named in my file. Thank you very much, naming it solved my problem.